# creating new variable attaching values of a variable(like month) and expanding the data horizontal wise?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```r
data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
           month = c("november", "december", "november", "december", "november", "december"),
           VariableA = c(2.5,4.5,4.2,1.4,3.4,1.5))
#>   id    month VariableA
#> 1  1 november       2.5
#> 2  1 december       4.5
#> 3  2 november       4.2
#> 4  2 december       1.4
#> 5  3 november       3.4
#> 6  3 december       1.5
```

I want to transform it like this:

```r
data.frame(id = c(1,2,3),
           NovemberVariableA = c(2.5,4.5,3.4),
           DecemberVariableA = c(4.5,1.4,1.5))
#>   id NovemberVariableA DecemberVariableA
#> 1  1               2.5               4.5
#> 2  2               4.5               1.4
#> 3  3               3.4               1.5
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

What is the best way to do it in R? I have tried unstack, but I am getting nonsense, and the problem is the id variable that needs to stay same. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_wider(df1, names_from = month, values_from = c(variableA, variableB))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), month = c("november", 
"december", "november", "december", "november", "december"), 
    variableA = c(2.5, 4.5, 4.2, 1.3, 4.3, 1.6), variableB = c(3L, 
    3L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: thank you very much! exactly what I was looking for.